# FileNotFoundError: [Errno2] | Python, using NumPy save and load

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy, errno

So here is my code that saves an array and later loads it so i can sum all the arrays, it works just fine, it creates the folder and the file itself, it saves and then loads the file and completes the task. ( [1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBE2i.jpg) ). Do you have any other idea how can i get this done without saving to an external file ?

Here is another code in the same project using the same numpy.save technique and it does not run, i tried a lot to find a solution, i used the exact path and had the same error ( 
[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3s2U.jpg))

Do  you have any idea how can i fix this ?
It drives me crazy!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read (again) the [how-to ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a snapshot of your code might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to write a file to a directory that doesn't exist.

Try using os.mkdir to create the directory to save into before calling np.save()

```
import os 
# Directory 
directory = "Ro"

# Add your path here or use os.getcwd() to get current working directory 
parent_dir = "/home/User/Documents"

# Path 
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory) 

# Create the directory 
# 'Ro' in 
# '/home / User / Documents' 
os.mkdir(path) 
print("Directory '%s' created" %directory)
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, but the folder exists and you can see it in the image, and as you can see in the first image the code is exactly tha same and works and in the second image it just doesnt work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question about a more efficient way to save/load arrays, I suggest declaring a list outside the loop, and appending the new array you create with each iteration to that list. You can access items from this list later in another loop to add them up (or whatever else you'd like to do...).

Here is an illustrative use of such a technique:

```
stack = []
for i in range(N):
    temp = numpy.random.rand(dim, dim)
    stack.append(temp)
```

I use `numpy` to generate random values for the 2-D array... that's not relevant to the example. The key is defining the list `stack` and appending to it the *temporary* array created in the loop `temp`.

Since it seems that your arrays are in entirety *float* arrays, you may as well convert `stack` to a numpy array for faster access - it then becomes a (2+1)D array. That's upto you, though.

Tell me if I hit the right spot. Thanks!

Comment: Τhank you very much actually that is why i am using it for to create a 2D matrix, and thats what i did, i found another way to express it, appreciate your answer